# what is the alternative for hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords in hive 3 version

Tags: hadoop, hive

what is the alternative for **hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords** in hive 3 version , Is this setting still valid in the latest versions of HIVE

Answer (score 0):

hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords setting was removed in Hive 2.3.0 onward with [HIVE-14872](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14872)

Use back-ticks (``) or rename identifiers: `timestamp` -> my_timestamp. No other alternatives.

Well, you can rename on serde level for JsonSerDe, not sure about other SerDe's, but is is still the same rename. [JsonSerDe](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) supports mapping of Hive reserved keywords:

`WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.ts" = "timestamp" )`, `ts` is a Hive column name, `timestamp` is JSON attribute name.